# Docker container not starting (docker start)

Tags: docker

I created the container with the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 52022:22 basickarl/docker-git-test
```

Here are the commands:

```
root@basickarl:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
root@basickarl:~# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                           PORTS               NAMES
e4ac54468455        basickarl/docker-git-test:latest   "/bin/bash"         7 minutes ago       Exited (0) 26 seconds ago                            adoring_lumiere     
22d7c5d83871        basickarl/docker-git-test:latest   "/bin/bash"         2 hours ago         Exited (127) About an hour ago                       thirsty_wright      
root@basickarl:~# docker attach --sig-proxy=false e4
FATA[0000] You cannot attach to a stopped container, start it first 
root@basickarl:~# docker start e4
e4
root@basickarl:~# docker attach --sig-proxy=false e4
FATA[0000] You cannot attach to a stopped container, start it first 
root@basickarl:~#
```

Not much to say really, I'm expecting the container to start and stay upp. Here are logs:

```
root@basickarl:~# docker logs e4
root@basickarl:~#
```

Comment: What do `docker logs e4` say?

Comment: @kojiro Updated question, doesn't seem to want to give me any.

Comment: oh, of course. You can't really attach to an exited shell. Even `docker start -ia $(docker ps -ql)` will fail in this case. Your best bet is to commit that container and start a new image.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You are trying to run `bash`, an interactive shell that requires a tty in order to operate.  It doesn't really make sense to run this in "detached" mode with `-d`, but you can do this by adding `-it` to the command line, which ensures that the container has a valid tty associated with it and that `stdin` remains connected:

```
docker run -it -d -p 52022:22 basickarl/docker-git-test
```

You would more commonly run some sort of long-lived non-interactive process (like `sshd`, or a web server, or a database server, or a process manager like `systemd` or `supervisor`) when starting detached containers.

If you are trying to run a service like `sshd`, you cannot simply run `service ssh start`.  This will -- depending on the distribution you're running inside your container -- do one of two things:

- It will try to contact a process manager like `systemd` or `upstart` to start the service.  Because there is no service manager running, this will fail.
- It will actually start `sshd`, but it will be started in the background.  This means that (a) the `service sshd start` command exits, which means that (b) Docker considers your container to have failed, so it cleans everything up.

If you want to run *just* ssh in a container, consider an example like [this](https://github.com/fedora-cloud/Fedora-Dockerfiles/tree/master/ssh).

If you want to run `sshd` *and other processes* inside the container, you will need to investigate some sort of process supervisor.

Comment: Yes, but to be sure, this will create a new container, not start the existing one.

Comment: This is why the existing one won't start.  Bash fails immediately because it does not have a tty attached.  This is also why there are no logs (because the process exits immediately without generating any output).

Comment: Ahh you just made it clear, of course it exits if I don't run a process of some sort.

Comment: Funny you mentioned `ssh` as that is what I'm trying to get to work, I run `docker run -d -p 52022:22 basickarl/docker-git-test service ssh start`, doesn't stay up though. Logs show that OpenSSH started though.

Comment: Nice info! Got it to work now via `docker run -d -p 52022:22 basickarl/docker-git-test /usr/sbin/sshd -D`.

Answer (score 3):

What I need is to use Docker with MariaDb on different port /3301/ on my Ubuntu machine because I already had MySql installed and running on 3306.

To do this after half day searching did it using:

```
docker run -it -d -p 3301:3306 -v ~/mdbdata/mariaDb:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root --name mariaDb mariadb
```

This pulls the image with latest MariaDb, creates container called mariaDb, and run mysql on port 3301. All data of which is located in home directory in /mdbdata/mariaDb.

To login in mysql after that can use:

```
mysql -u root -proot -h 127.0.0.1 -P3301
```

Used sources are:

The answer of Iarks in this article /using -it -d was the key :) /

[how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04)

[installing-and-using-mariadb-via-docker](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/installing-and-using-mariadb-via-docker/)

[mariadb-and-docker-use-cases-part-1](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/mariadb-and-docker-use-cases-part-1)

Good luck all!

Answer (score 0):

You can view the logs and check if there is an issue in your Dockerfile or any other issue.

[image]