# docker start <container ID> doesn't do anything

Tags: docker

If I spin up a Docker container with:

```
docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

and then exit. I can see the container using

```
docker ps -a
```

However, if I try and restart the container with

```
docker start <container ID>
```

I just get  echoed back and returned to the command prompt.

What am I missing?

Comment: What's the CMD or ENTRYPOINT of the container in question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker container not starting (docker start)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957653/docker-container-not-starting-docker-start)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy is `docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash` not the CMD?

Comment: Yes, explicitly passing `bash` as an argument is providing a CMD **for the one invocation where you pass it**. That's not a persistent setting; the persistent CMD is set in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After running `docker start <container ID>` to restart the container try running a `docker ps` to ensure it's actually running.

If it IS running and you want to run commands on a bash shell from within the container, you can run the below command. In your case it would be :

`docker exec -it <container ID> bash`

Comment: How does this answer the question? You have not explained why `docker start` does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

use docker start with '-ai' so it attaches to container interactively

```
docker start -ai <container ID>
```

**CAUTION!** This will relaunch the process that this container is supposed to run:

- If it is defined by a Dockerfile with a `CMD` instruction, then it will run it.
- If it was a container for building a Dockerfile, the last failed instruction will be retried.

Comment: How does this answer the question? You have not explained why `docker start` does nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
docker start <container name>
```