# The command is not executed at startup

Tags: docker

Specify command with docker run:

```
$ docker run -it --name python3 -v "$PWD":/hoge -w /hoge python:3 python --version
Python 3.10.5
```

Start:

```
$ docker start python3
python3
```

As shown above, `docker run` and `docker start` behave differently.

Inspect has Cmd:

```
$ docker inspect python3              
[
 ...
        "Config": {
          ...
            "Cmd": [
                "python",
                "--version"
            ],
            "Image": "python:3",
          ...
        },
        ...
    }
]
```

And the php is same:

```
$ docker run -it --name foo -v "$PWD":/hoge -w /hoge php:7.4-cli php --version
PHP 7.4.30 (cli) (built: Jul 12 2022 08:38:38) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

$ docker start foo
foo
```

This is an experimental code.
It has no practical significance.

Why can't they be the same in `docker run` and `docker start`?

How do I get `docker start` to execute the command I specified at `docker run`?

Comment: I think you probably need `docker start -a` to see the container's output; also [docker start <container ID> doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901968/docker-start-container-id-doesnt-do-anything).  But in practice you almost never need `docker start` and I wouldn't worry about this, `docker run` already runs the command and it's safe to delete the container once it's done.

Comment: it was output with `-a`!  Thank you.